# Mobile - scroll event removes z-index

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css, mobile

I have a strange bug, which is happening on android and ios browsers (all of them).

Menu is hidden, and user can show the menu with a click on a button. When the user scroll the page, the menu is gone, hidden, removed. I really don't know :/.

This is the css for the menu:

```
.right-sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 15px;
    z-index: 100 !important;
    display: none;
    width: 50%;
    background: white;
  }
```

This is js for showing/hiding menu:

```
$('.action-bar').on('click', function(){
        $('.right-sidebar').toggle('fast');
        $(this).find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-minus');

         checkSidbars($(this));
    });
```

What is going on here?

Comment: `checkSidbars` looks like a typo. What's the function do?

Comment: add your markup, add your `checkSidbars` funciton.